# Why are these functions working different?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the state of a property after making an API call only if the component hasn't been unmounted. In the first function the variable "unmounted" is initialize inside the function "Component"; in this case I'm getting this warning: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application."

In the second function I initialize the variable "unmounted" globally and in this case I'm not getting any warning.

### Shows a warning:

```
function Component() {
  const [emailSent, setEmailSent] = useState(false);

  var unmounted = false;
  async function handleClickEvent() {
  try {
   await AuthApi.sendRecoverAccountEmail('123');
   !unmounted && setEmailSent(true);
  } catch (err) {
    !unmounted && setIsSendingEmail(false);
  }
 }

 useEffect(() => {
   return () => {
    unmounted = true;
   };
 }, []);
}
```

### No warnings:

```
var unmounted = false;
function Component() {
const [emailSent, setEmailSent] = useState(false);

async function handleSendEmail(formValues) {
 try {
  await AuthApi.sendRecoverAccountEmail('123');
  !unmounted && setEmailSent(true);
 } catch (err) {
  !unmounted && setIsSendingEmail(false);
 }
}

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
   unmounted = true;
  };
 }, []);
}
```

Anyone can explain why is this happening?

Comment: perhaps add `unmounted` as a state variable. `const [unmounted, setUnmounted] = useState(false);` and go from there

Answer (score 3):

On your first example, `unmounted` will always be `false` after each render.

Here's the right way without using an global instance:

```js
function Component() {
  const [emailSent, setEmailSent] = useState(false);
  const unmounted = useRef(false);

  async function handleSendEmail(formValues) {
    try {
      await AuthApi.sendRecoverAccountEmail('123');
      !unmounted.current && setEmailSent(true);
    } catch (err) {
      !unmounted.current && setIsSendingEmail(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      unmounted.current = true;
    };
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It's working fine. But there's no re-render after unmounting the component (I'm going to a separate route). The "unmounted" variable is not being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question. You might find the [FAQ about hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#can-i-skip-an-effect-on-updates) useful, as I think it addresses your question rather specifically.

In your first example, your unmounted var is part of your component properties, where in the second example, it is just picked up as part of the javascript closure.

Usually, you want to make sure that you change the mounted parameter as part of the [componentDidUnmount lifecycle method.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

I think if you add unmounted into the list of dependencies, it might work? I normally use react from another framework in Clojurescript, so I'm not completely familiar with the semantics of the main javascript interface, but that would at least be why you're getting a warning for the first example.

In your first example, what happens if you change the last part to the following?

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
   unmounted = true;
  };
 }, [unmounted]);
}
```

You may need to define unmounted as a more formal react property instead of just a property enclosed in your component.

Comment: Your answer has few flaws:
1. There is no componentDidUnmount, I presume you mean componentWillUnmount.
2. In the array of the useEffect's optional parameter, you are supposed to pass props or state only.